# sorting in unix by file size

Tags: sorting, unix

I have a unix file with data like:

```
35|ag
0|ca
22.0 K|nt
43.8 G|ct
90.0 M|se
2.4 M|ew
1.6 K|et
0|er
0|dr
18|ld
```

Output:

```
43.8 G|ct   
90.0 M|se
2.4 M|ew    
22.0 K|nt
1.6 K|et
35|ag
18|ld
0|ca
0|er
0|dr
```

I need to sort this in decreasing order of size. I could convert this to uniform size such as bytes and then sort them, but I was hoping if it could be sorted directly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exact version of OS?  That matters because the tools you have available will differ on different UNIX versions.

Comment: Linux 2.6.32 - (not sure though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU sort. `man sort`:

```
   -h, --human-numeric-sort
          compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)
```

but we need to remove the spaces from the first field. Using `tr`

```
$ cat file | tr -d ' ' | sort -h -r -t\| -k 1
43.8G|ct
90.0M|se
2.4M|ew
22.0K|nt
1.6K|et
35|ag
18|ld
0|er
0|dr
0|ca
```