# Sort Data volume number

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Can you let me know if there is a way to sort Data volume numbers like the following ones please:

want to sort the following lines based on the first column

```
7.9G User1   2020-05-07     
529M User2  2020-04-24 
49M User3   2020-04-29 
43M User4   2020-04-23
```

Thanks

Comment: This question was already answered here: [sorting in unix by file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47856564/sorting-in-unix-by-file-size)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sort, use the `-h` option:

```
sort -k1,1h file
```

From `man sort`:

```
-h, --human-numeric-sort 
      compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)

-k, --key=KEYDEF
      sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type

KEYDEF  is  F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position,
where F is a field number and C a character position in the field;
both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.
```